# why rear element in a queue points to null

Tags: data-structures, queue, stack

In a linked list implementation of queue, why rear element (inserted last) in a queue points to null? And in linked list implementation of a stack why very first element (inserted first) points to the null?

[image]

[image]

The reason I am asking this question is that I am implementing stack and queue in java using linked list and implementation changes if null is present let us say at the front of a queue OR null is present at the next of the top in a stack.

Comment: What else would it point to? The point is to signify the end of the structure. That said, these are somewhat unclear diagrams, taken out of context -- where are they from?

Comment: Do you know any correct diagram?

Comment: It's not so much incorrect as it is not necessarily easy to understand taken out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both structures are linked lists. Each node has a `next` pointer to the next node. When there is no next node, then we need to decide which value to put there. It is convenient to store a null-pointer value there, as that value can never be confused with a real pointer.

This null-pointer is often important to identify a node as being the last one.
For instance, the `pop` method in a stack implementation, will need to take care of what happens when the *last* (bottom) element is removed. A `pop` would be implemented along these lines:

```cpp
if (top == nullptr) return nullptr; // Stack is empty
Node * node = top;
top = top->next;
free(node);
```

So, as an empty stack is identified by `top === nullptr`, it is important that the bottom element of the stack has its `next` pointer set to `nullptr`. Only then will the empty-condition be correctly set after removing the bottom-element.

In case the data structure maintains a reference to the last node (like `*rear` in the case of the queue), then in theory we could leave the last node's `next` pointer's value undefined (i.e. to any value). We could then identify a node as being the last node by comparing its address with the `rear` pointer, without ever having to look at that (undefined, and thus unsafe) `next` pointer. But it is just better practice to store an explicit null-pointer there, which leads to (more) elegant code, and leads to better error reporting in case the code has a bug by which it mistakenly follows this last node's `next` pointer.